# Jquery and ApiGility login strategy

Tags: javascript, jquery, laminas-api-tools

I would like to use Apigility and Jquery as a login strategy into my application. I am struggling to understand how to do this.

My setup is as follows:

[image: enter image description here][1]

The client and the Login api are trusted as they are both part of my application.

What I am struggling to understand is the process of taking the username and password from my form, processing it in JQuery, then using the Apigility authorization strategy to ensure that the request is genuine and to pass it securely onto the required login end point.

**I have a standard login form:**

[image]

The user enters a username and password and clicks "login".
Jquery validates the data and now I need to send the users credentials to the Login End Point... How to do this with ApiGility, I am not sure...

I have been reading the documentation here: https://apigility.org/documentation/auth/authentication-oauth2 and I don't quite get it.

**This is what I have setup with ApiGility.**

1. I have created a Login end point in ApiGility
2. This end point can only accept a Post request.
3. The end point requires authorization to be accessed.

**Now how to interact with this?**

1. As I am using a client side script (Even though it is my own app), I cant use traditional Client id and password as there is no way to secure this information in JQuery without exposing it to the world.
2. In its place, I should use an implicit grant, i.e. a client identity, with no password.
3. To get an implicit grant, I need to re-direct the user to Apigilities: http://example.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=testclient2&redirect_uri=/oauth/receivecode&state=1 end point, ensuring I include the user name and password in the post request.
4. When a user is re-directed, they must click on a yes or a no button, if yes, a token is created and a session is generated (storing the customers username and password) and returned. This token I store on the customers machine, using a session.
5. Now that I have a token, I use this token to gain access to my secure Login End Point.
6. Once I have access to the Login Controller, I now use the token to get the username and password from the session.
7. Finally - check the credentials and return: true / false etc.

How close or far off am I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Yes you can, as long as you use a properly configured (secure) [`https` connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS). By using a security certificate you will ensure encryption of the data being sent and received by the client and it will be unreadable when intercepted.

**2.** When using implicit grant you will still need to authenticate your client with a username and password. Check the workflow [here in this OAuth documentation](http://oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2/grants/implicit.html#implicit-grant).

My idea is you are missing the fact that you need a secure connection. I would suggest setting up `https` on your server and then follow [the `Apigility` OAuth documentation](https://apigility.org/documentation/auth/authentication-oauth2). It seems quite complete and I think you should be able to manage by following their instructions.